# Display a gee featureCollection on a leaflet map

Tags: python, leaflet, google-earth-engine, jupyter-notebook

I'm using the python GEE api and ipyleaflet in a Jupyter Notebook and I'd like to retrieve an asset (FeatureCollection) and display it as an overlay on my map.

The retrieving work just fine

```py
asset_descripsion = 'Glad_' + country_selection + '_boundaries'
folder = ee.data.getAssetRoots()[0]['id'] + '/'

asset = ee.FeaturCollection(folder+asset_descripsion)
```

I also have a ipyleaflet map

```
m = Map(center=center, zoom=zoom)
dark_matter_layer = basemap_to_tiles(basemaps.CartoDB.DarkMatter)
m.add_layer(dark_matter_layer)
```

but I don't know how to add a layer based on a ee.FeatureCollection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presumed there would be an easy way to convert FeatureCollection to GeoJSON and load up as a layer in ipyleaflet but it is not straightforward. As far as I can see there is no direct way of doing this. However, as a workaround, [you can get a download url to your FeatureCollection](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#ee.featurecollection.getdownloadurl) (JSON is in the options but it did not work for me but CSV did) and then read the features from there as JSON to add as a layer to ipyleaflet. Something similar to in the line of:

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
import codecs
import json

url = asset.getDownloadURL("csv")
response = urlopen(url)
cr = csv.DictReader(codecs.iterdecode(response, 'utf-8'))

for row in cr:
    geojson = ipyleaflet.GeoJSON(json.loads(row['.geo']))
    m.add_layer(geojson)
```